# Elasticsearch 6.3 (AWS) snapshot restore progress ERROR: "/_recovery is not allowed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

- I take manual snapshots of an Elasticsearch index
- These are stored in a snapshot repo on S3
- I have created a new ES cluster, also version 6.3
- I have connected the new cluster to the S3 snapshot repo via python script method mentioned in this blog post: https://medium.com/docsapp-product-and-technology/aws-elasticsearch-manual-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-7e9783cdaecb
- I have confirmed that the new cluster has access to the snapshot repo via the `GET /_snapshot/manual-snapshot-repo/_all?pretty` command
- I have initiated a snapshot restore to this new cluster via:

  POST /_snapshot/manual-snapshot-repo/snapshot_name/_restore
  {
  "indices": "reports",
  "ignore_unavailable": false,
  "include_global_state": false
  }
- It is clear that this operation has at least partially succeeded as the cluster status has gone from "green" to "yellow" and a GET request to `/_cluster/health` yields information that suggests actions are occuring on an otherwise empty cluster... not to mention storage is starting to be utilized (when viewing cluster health on AWS).
- I would very much like to monitor the progress of the restore operation.
- Elasticsearch docs suggest to use the Recovery API. Docs Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-recovery.html
- It is clear from the docs that `GET /_recovery?human` or `GET /my_index/_recovery?human` should yield restore progress.

However, I encounter the following error:

```
"Message": "Your request: '/_recovery' is not allowed."
```

I get the same message when attempting the GET command in the following ways:

- Via Kibana dev tools
- Via chrome address bar (It's just a GET operation after all)
- Via Advanced REST Client (a Chrome app)

I have not been able to locate any other mention of this particular error message.

How can I utilize the `GET /_recovery?human` command on my ElasticSearch 6.3 clusters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon managed Elasticsearch does not have all the endpoints available.

For version 6.3 you can check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_6_3) for the endpoints available, and `_recovery` is not on the list, that is why you get that message.

Without the `_recovery` endpoint you will need to rely on `_cluster/health`.